# Regarding a potential generalisation of Krylov-Bogolubov theorem

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $(\mathbb{X},d)$ be a **Compact Metric Space** and $T:(\mathbb{X},d) \longrightarrow (\mathbb{X},d)$ be a **Continuous Mapping**. Let $B(\mathbb{X})$ be $\sigma$ - Algebra of all Borel subsets of $\mathbb{X}$.

It is well-known in **Ergodic Theory** that **Krylov-Bogolubov** theorem guarantees the existence of $T-$ invariant borel probability measure $\mu$ defined on $B(\mathbb{X})$ ($T-$ invariant means $\mu(B) = \mu(T^{-1}(B))$ for every $B\in B(\mathbb{X})$).

Via **Riesz Representation Theorem** we identify the set $M(\mathbb{X})$ (the set of all borel probability measures defined on $B(\mathbb{X})$) with a subset of the set of all positive normalised continuous linear functionals on $C(\mathbb{X})$ (the space of all real continuous functions defined on $\mathbb{X}$).

Since Riesz Representation Theorem has been generalised for a Locally Compact Hausdorff topological space (that is called Riesz-Markov-Kakutani theorem).

I would like to enquire whether it is possible to generalise **Krylov-Bogolubov** theorem for a Locally Compact Hausdorff topological space.

To understand the whole image, you can consult **An Introduction To Ergodic Theory**, **Peter Walters**, 1982. Chapter **6**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to formulate the appropriate generalization. Here I will assume you want the theorem for any $T: X \to X$ which is continuous, or you maybe even assume it to be invertible. There is no hope to find an invariant *probability* measure, so you may want to just find an invariant *positive* (Radon) measure. This is still not possible in general:

Take $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $T(x) = 2x$. This is a homeomorphism. It has no invariant positive measure: If $T_* \mu = \mu$ is invariant, let us assume some finite open interval $(a,b)$ has finite measure (otherwise all open sets have measure infinity, contradicting the requirement from a Radon measure to be finite on compact sets). WLOG $a > 0$. We claim $\mu((0,b))=\infty$, again contradicting fineness on compact sets. Indeed, $\mu((\frac{a}{2^n}, \frac{b}{2^n}))) = \mu((a,b))$ for all $n \geq 0$, and, these intervals are contained in $(0,b)$ yet an infinite number of them are disjoint. This shows the claim. $\blacksquare$

If you want to know more about dynamics with infinite positive measrues, look up infinite ergodic theory.

Comment: I would be very grateful if you were able to explain the paragraph after (We claim......).

Comment: @Neilhawking If we prove $\mu ((0,b)) = \infty$ we are done, since a Radon measure has to satisfy $\mu([0,b]) < \infty$ as it is compact. If you look at all of the shrunk intervals obtained from $(0,b)$ by $(\frac{a}{2^n}, \frac{b}{2^n}) = T^-n((a,b))$, which all have the same measure. you can easily choose (say inductively) infinitely many $n$'s so that they are pairewise disjoint. But by Sigma additivity this implies $\mu((a,b)) = \infty$

Comment: Thank you for your explanation